# Configuration dependent on platform

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, configuration

I have a web application .netcore web app which I wish to have platform agnostic. Depending on the deployment of the application i.e. docker or aws I want to be able to use different configuration methods for the application.

Using docker secrets I add the Json files in startup with the path /run/secrets but how could I use a different method for configuration for AWS secrets using the AWS SDK.

How would I change this to use AWS SDK secrets manager if the app is deployed to AWS,

Thanks

Example startup.cs is

```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var basePath = (env.EnvironmentName.Equals("Development") ? "c:" : "");

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .AddJsonFile($"{basePath}/run/secrets/xx1", optional: true)
                            .AddJsonFile($"{basePath}/run/secrets/xx2", optional: true)
                            .AddJsonFile($"{basePath}/run/secrets/xx2", optional: true)
                            .AddJsonFile($"{basePath}/run/secrets/xx4", optional: true);

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

Comment: You could consider using environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you could use the preprocessor. You can add conditional compilation symbols and only include the code you need for the specific target. These symbols can be set in your project properties in the build tab or at the top of your file using #define.

For example:

```
#define aws
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
#if docker
        Console.WriteLine("Build for docker.");
#endif
#if aws
        Console.WriteLine("Build for aws.");
#endif
    }
}
```